# Convert string to boolean using database expression in Django (for generated field)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following models code:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    barcode_data = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        default="",
    )

    @property
    def is_scannable(self):
        if self.barcode_data:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Basically, if `barcode_data` is not empty, `is_scannable` returns `True`. I want to turn `is_scannable` into a generated field, something like this:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    barcode_data = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        default="",
    )
    is_scannable = models.GeneratedField(
        expression=...,
        output_field=models.BooleanField(),
        db_persist=True,
    )
```

I've read the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/database-functions/, but it seems like there isn't really a function to convert a string to boolean based on whether it is empty or not. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: bool(a_string) returns True, if the string is not empty and False if the string is empty

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `__exact` to evaluate the value of the `barcode_data` field.

```
from django.db.models import Case, When

    ...
    is_scannable = models.GeneratedField(
        expression=Case(
            When(
                name__exact="",
                then=False,
            ),
            default=True,
        ),
        output_field=models.BooleanField(),
        db_persist=True,
    )
```

This should produce the following SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE
    "app_product" (
        "barcode_data" varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        "is_scannable" boolean GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN "barcode_data" = '' THEN false ELSE true END) STORED
    );
```

*I didn't check the functionality of the code.*